# How to get the max length of the key or value in the list of dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the maximum length of the last key-value pair (in each dict) in the list of ordered dictionary.

Example:

```
# below is the list of ordered dict
my_list = [{'Table': 'Config', 'Column': 'config_id', 'DataType': 'int'},
       {'Table': 'Config', 'Column': 'config_name', 'DataType': 'varchar'},
       {'Table': 'Config', 'Column': 'config_value', 'DataType': 'numeric'}]
 # Expected out put
 Out put: 8 # as the key (in this case "DataType") has max chars  and if any value for the same key has max char then it will return that value.
```

Any Suggestions!

Comment: Like so? `max([len(k) for k in d.keys() for d in my_list])`

Comment: No this give max length of all the keys in the dict. @jDo

Comment: So in this case, you are interested only in this pair: `'DataType': 'numeric'` which is the last one?

Comment: @Pradeep It's really strange. I had it working in my interpreter but now it doesn't work :S `>>> [max([len(k) for k in d.keys() for d in my_list]) if not len(k) > d[k] else d[k]]`. Output:
`[8]`. Then I added a value under one of the keys that was longer than any key (so that would be returned instead of the number 8): `>>> [max([len(k) for k in d.keys() for d in my_list]) if len(k) > d[k] else d[k]]`. Output: `['Condddddddddddddddfig']`. Now I just get syntax errors!?

Comment: try this '[max([len(k) for d in my_list for k in d ])]'. @jDo

Comment: @Pradeep Yes, thank you! "k for d"!

Comment: You commented me *But I am looking only the last key value pair to find the max length.*  but for C Panda you asked something else: *I need the last key-value pair in each dict*. This misleads members as it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Your dictionaries are not ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `my_list :: [collections.OrderedDict]`, the following works.

```
kvs = (list(d.items())[-1] for d in my_list) # [(last_key1, last_val1),..]
words = [max(k,v,key=len) for k,v in kvs]    # [max_key1_val1, max_key2_val2,..]
chars = [len(word) for word in words]        # [len(max_key1_val1),...]
ans = max(chars)                             # max() of all
```

If this is not what you wanted, do comment below. I will improve the answer.

Comment: Not exactly! this gives the last inserted dict in the list. But I need the last key-value pair in each dict. so that i can find the max length. @C Panda

Comment: *I need the last key-value pair in each dict* this is something new you did not mention in your question at all. Please edit your question accordingly and make it clear. @Pradeep